# Adapt query to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to adapt this query to rails I do not know how to adapt it due to the appearance of errors, this is the original query:

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(10),Fecha,103) as Fechax, count(*) NoPedidos
FROM pedidos
WHERE cancelado=0 AND
group by month(Fechax),Convert(varchar(10),Fecha,103)
order by month(Fechax)
```

This is what i have done so far:

```
query = select('Convert(varchar(10),Fecha,103) AS Fechax, count(*) NoPedidos')
        .where("Cancelado = 0")
```

How can I add group_by and order_by?

Answer (score 0):

query = select('Convert(varchar(10),Fecha,103) AS Fechax, count(*) NoPedidos')
        .where("Cancelado = 0").group("column_name").order("column desc/asc")

Answer (score 0):

The code would look like this:

```
query = Pedido.select('Convert(varchar(10),Fecha,103) AS Fechax, count(*) NoPedidos').where("Cancelado = ?", 0).group("month(Fechax), Convert(varchar(10),Fecha,103)").order("month(Fecha)")
```

And you can specify the order (ASC/DESC) in the order() method. I think it should work for you now.

Read this, it helped me a lot in dealing with ActiveRecord: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group

Comment: thanks for answer, I get this error with your query TinyTds::Error: Invalid column name 'Fechax'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT Convert(varchar(10),Fecha,103) AS Fechax, count(*) AS NoPedidos FROM [pedidos] WHERE (Cancelado = 0) GROUP BY month(Fechax), Convert(varchar(10),Fecha,103)  ORDER BY month(Fecha)'